# Type traits which are true for all const/volatile/signed/unsigned version of a fundamental type

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits, qualifiers

Consider the following tests:

```
std::is_same<T, bool>::value
std::is_same<T, char>::value
std::is_same<T, short int>::value
std::is_same<T, int>::value
std::is_same<T, long int>::value
std::is_same<T, long long int>::value
std::is_same<T, float>::value
std::is_same<T, double>::value
std::is_same<T, long double>::value
```

The problem is if `T = const unsigned char`, all tests will be false, and I would like this one `std::is_same<T, char>::value` to be true. Or if `T = volatile signed long long int` I would like `std::is_same<T, long long int>::value` to be true. How to do that with `type_traits` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`std::remove_cv`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv) to remove `const` and `volatile` if present:

```
std::is_same<std::remove_cv<T>::type, long long int>::value;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [std::remove_cv](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/remove_cv/) to take care of the const-volatile specifiers.

And you can use [std::make_signed](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/make_signed/) to take care of the signed/unsigned issue. Although, I don't particularly like that idea (is `unsigned char` really the same as `char`? No.).

```
std::is_same< std::make_signed< std::remove_cv<T> >, char >::value;
```

Will be true for any of `char`, `unsigned char`, `const char`, `const unsigned char`, and the volatile versions of those.

Comment: I design a class to detect data models of files produced by heterogeneous system, and signed/unsigned versions of types are encoded with the same amount of bytes.

Comment: An `unsigned char`, a `signed char` and a regular `char` are three distinct types (see §3.9.1.1). Therefore the example will not be true, since you produce a `signed char` and compare it with a regular `char`. Feel free to test it: https://ideone.com/T8QdYw